# Touching an AC wire

Tags: ac

What will happen if a person touches a 220V AC live wire while he/she is not in contact with the ground?

Comment: *"... while he/she is not in contact with the ground"* Levitating? Yogic flying? Or just insulated?

Comment: https://youtu.be/9Lbmis-VUW0?t=4m42s

Comment: What happens to a bird sitting on top of a high-tension wire?

Answer (score 9):

If you only touch a single spot and you wouldn't have any electrical connections to any other potentials anywhere in your body, nothing would happen. But in real life, your body is at least capacitively connected to earth. So in reality, some current will flow from the point of contact to other parts of your body and you will feel at least a sort of buzzing tingling, which can be quite scary. The amount will vary depending on how isolated you really are.

Comment: Now, next question should be "where the hell this displacement current flows" :D

Comment: As it's AC, it keeps on charging and discharging the body's capacitance. And it flows to and from the leakage points between you and earth. You're seldom quite completely isolated from the earth.

Comment: Yeah, i mean that the whole mesh is closed on the power plant :)

Answer (score 0):

You know tesla coils?

You'd feel a bit like those circles were travelling up and down your arm until you let go. Then you'd feel pain.

Experience: unscrewed a lightbulb from a desk lamp and stuck my finger in it when I was little.

Higher voltages get you thrown off ladders, but more due to loss of muscles than sparks and smoke like in the movies - though things (like metal) metal that you were using to touch higher voltages can potentially melt

Comment: Stuff like a short circuit with a large piece of metal is one of those things where the old saying "it's the current that matters" really _is_ true, since thick metal objects can basically be treated as having zero resistance and it's limited by the voltage source's ability to deliver current. A 12 volt car battery can melt a screwdriver.